Film with a wizard and a cyclops?
What is the name of an old film where the main character's friend is a wizard/mage and they are chased by cyclops? It is for sure one of those sword-and-sandals or sword-and-magic films.
In the film, the main character (a younger boy) and his friend (a wizard) are chased by a cyclops. And the main character asks him, "What did you do to them?" and the wizard answers, "Well, what I didn't... I refused to marry his daughter...".
In another scene, one of the characters knelt down at the bank of a lake/river, did some magic with his hands, and suddenly saw the face of his beloved girlfriend in the water.
I saw it when I was a small kid, like 30 years ago. Any idea what the name of the film could be?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?

Another possibility is Krull, where there's both a wizard (played by David Battley) and a Cyclops (played by Bernard Bresslaw); the cyclops was an ally though.

Oh Brother, Where Art Thou? Has a Wizard and a Cyclops…

The Seventh Voyage of Sinbad (1958) has a magician and a cyclops, though some of the above description doesn't fit.

This is Wizards of the Lost Kingdom (1985).

Simon, son of the wizard, must flee when the empire is overthrown by the evil Shurka. Schooled in the arts of magic, he must find the Ring of Magic and the Sword of Power and defeated the wizard who killed his father. He is joined in his quest by the swordmaster Kor, his faithful creature Gulfax, and the Forest Wizard Hurla.

As indicated above, this is a medieval fantasy film in which Simon -- the teenage son of the good wizard, Wulfrik -- is on a quest to recapture his kingdom from the evil wizard, Shurka. Simon has some magical ability and is aided by a wandering swordsman named Kor the Conqueror.
At around 31 minutes in, Simon is sitting by a lake, then casts a spell with his hands and sees the face of his girlfriend, Princess Aura, in the water (she's being held prisoner by Shurka).



At around 54 minutes in, Simon finds Kor tied to a tree by a cyclops, and has the following discourse with him:

SIMON: Has he been following you long?
KOR: Across three kingdoms.
SIMON: What did you do?
KOR: It's what I didn't do.
SIMON: What's that?
KOR: I didn't marry his sister.
SIMON: Why not?
KOR: Because she's his twin sister.






The film is currently available to watch for free on Tubi and on YouTube.

As befits a Roger Corman film, there are a bunch of reused effects, particularly from Sorceress (1982).

Many thanks! That is the film.

@LogicDictates I think that your description of Simon as a teenager exaggerates, unless his age is mentioned in the movie.  It is true that the available evidence indicates that the actor Vidal Peterson turned 15 about the time of the filming, and so was technically a teenager, but all the stills I can find make Simon look like a pre teen kid.  I only met one boy in my life who looked that childlike and adorable but claimed to be a teenager, and one of my companions said she didn't believe his age.  So it seems more accurate to describe Simon as a child or as a preteen.

@M. A. Golding - He does look on the young side for a teenager and I don't think his age was mentioned in the film, but like you said, the actor was 15, and he has a pretty deep voice in the film, which makes his casting an odd choice if he was specifically meant to be a preteen. It's also suggested that the character, Simon, was going to be ruling a kingdom at the end of the film, and the adult antagonist was trying to persuade Simon's girlfriend, Aura, to marry him. So, while there is some uncertainty, I lean towards the probability that the character was meant to be in the 13-15 range.
